# How to center vertically items on Toolstrip (Flow mode)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my Winforms application I have a toolbar that contains many items (buttons with icon 32px, labels and comboboxes).

I decided to set the `Toolstrip.LayoutStyle` property from the default `HorizontalStackWithOverflow` to `Flow` in order to allow the toolbar split automatically on more rows when user have a very low resolution monitor or he/she resize the window.

The problem is that all labels and comboboxes are aligned to the top of Toolstrip when I change the `LayoutStyle`.

Does exist a property or any other workaround that allow me to center them vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you mean, the label isn't as tall as, say, a button.  And it gets aligned improperly with LayoutStyle = Flow.  Ugh.  You can work around it by changing the Padding property of the label.  To do this properly, you should however do this in the form's OnLoad() method override, the label will be taller when you run on a machine with a higher video DPI setting.

Comment: This method works for ToolStripLabel. Do you know why, even if I set Padding for ToolStripTextBox, it is always displayed to the top edge of ToolStrip?